# Is it possible to create a wormhole by adding density?

Tags: black-holes

A black hole is an object that has infinite mass, which is thought to tear a hole in space-time fabric. Would it be possible to not have a black hole, but have an object with near-infinite density, which is able to tear a hole in space-time fabric as well?

EDIT

The context for this is in my universe, Humanity is experimenting with tech(s) called GENESIS. One of their projects has to do with FTL by tearing holes in space, called RAPTURE. The adding of density(or mass) has to do with a proposed method.

Comment: You are mistaken.  Black holes have a finite mass, but contain a singularity that has infinite density.  This singularity is concealed by an event horizon from which light cannot return, hence the "black".   Do you perhaps mean add mass to a black hole?

Comment: Could you provide some worldbuilding context for the question, else I fear it'll be closed as off-topic?

Comment: Black hole have finite mass, we suppose they have infinite density, all mass in a single point called singularity. This is predicted by Theory of relativity, but in fact there are no proof since we can't see thought event horizon. Theory of relativity also predicts the existence of wormholes, but today there are no proof nor observations of such objects.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:

### No

Nothing suggests that a black hole tears a "hole in space-time fabric".  Physics work in interesting ways beyond the event horizon of a black hole, but it doesn't go anywhere but into the mass of the black hole.  While suggestions have been made that a white hole is the expression of that mass elsewhere, no candidate white holes have been observed, and traversal of that bridge is impossible regardless.

A traverseable wormhole is far less about the density of the matter at its mouth, and more about the use of exotic matter (matter with negative mass/energy) to make it a nondestructive passage between points in space.

I would suggest going over the [wormhole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole) entry on Wikipedia and its bibliography so you have a sense of how they theoretically operate.